# Am I liable to tax even if my salary is less than 1 lac per annum in India

Tags: income-tax, india, tax-deduction

I working with a small firm, my monthly salary is Rs. 8000/- for that my employer is deducting 10% ie Rs. 800/- monthly as TDS.

As my annual salary is less than 1 lac I know I wont have to pay any income tax, how to claim that deducted amount or how can I know complete details! Any one help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my employer is deducting 10% ie Rs. 800/- monthly as TDS.

This is incorrect. Your employer should not be deducting any Taxes. Are you sure you are shown as Employee. Or is the company treating you as a contractor.

> How to claim that deducted amount

You would need to file Tax Returns at year end. You would need to use Saral Form, or best use the [Income Tax website](https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/) for no charge. Fill the details and claim refunds. It generally takes a year to get the funds back.

**Edit:**
As explained, you need to file returns. Show that actual tax is zero, tax paid is x amount. Claim the refund. You can do this online using Income Tax website it will automatically calculate the refund. Generally refunds come through in few months to year.

Comment: thankyou! I just found out that, for 6 months while I'm in training phase, I work as a contract employee!

Comment: Hello @Dheer Can you help me how to claim that amount I don't know much about this.